# How to get the sum of total row where values greater than 20 and drop those less than a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Screenshot of the data
[image]

I'm trying to clean some data to answer questions on it. I appended a sum row and whilst most of the sum of the column add up to 1, if I want to find the top 10 or 20 common illnesses, how do I 'filter' by the 'Total' which is a row? For instance, I would like to have all the columns (I think index 5 to 135) where the 'Total' ( which is the last row in the dataframe) is > 20 and then save those for the main analysis.

Thank you

Comment: I get an error, keyError: 'Total'  ? :S

Comment: I just realized 'Total' is a row. See @shubham-sharma answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can use **indexing with `.loc`**

```
df.loc[:, df.loc['Total'] > 20]
```

Comment: I get this error: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @LauraFernandes probably you have mixed datatypes in `Total` row. Check: `df.loc[:, pd.to_numeric(df.loc['Total'], errors='coerce') > 20]`

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!! I spent hours on it :') . Your above code worked!! Can I bug you on one last thing - how to make panda plots with this 'Total' given it has mixed datatypes? For example if I try new_df.loc['Total'].plot() it says no numeric data to plot

Comment: Glad to help! You  have to change the dtype to numeric. `pd.to_numeric(df.loc['Total'], errors='coerce').plot()`

Comment: Hey, will I always need to use pd.to_numeric? What if I want to just plot using matplotlib and I want to plot Total vs Molars for example, how would that work :( Thanks

Comment: @LauraFernandes In that case convert the row to numeric type then store the row into some variable, and plot using matplotlib.

Comment: Totals = pd.to_numeric(new_df.loc['Total'],errors = 'coerce')                        long_claws = new_df['Claw/nails overlong']                                                                      plt.scatter(Totals, long_claws).    <-- I tried this but I keep getting errors that x and y must be the same size :((

Comment: @LauraFernandes Its very difficult to tell what you are trying to do here, maybe if you can provide a little bit more context, I might be able to help.

Comment: I would like to make several plots where it shows total vs the breed, and/or most common disorders again using the total.

Comment: Laura, I guess you are approaching this problem the hard way, there should be another simpler way by which you can achieve the same thing. TBH, I don't see the  relevance of calculating the total row in the first place.

Comment: Oh okay, it's just because there are 135 columns so I thought creating/appending a row of totals would help investigate the top 10 or top 20 common disorders and then cross referencing them against breeds or male/female and creating plots accordingly.

Comment: I would suggest to first identify the disease column names, then do a groupby on `Breeds` and sum the values in disease columns this will help you in identifying the count of particular disease per breeed. After this you can easily plot the data using matplotlib or seaborn.

Comment: can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72425505/14127922?stw=2

Comment: Hey Laura! I see that you already got the answer.

Comment: kind-off but could do with more help :D

Comment: let me check the question

Comment: thanks it was related to suggestion above.